# Message not saving to database

Tags: asp.net-core

I am facing an issue with saving message to my database. I am using Twilio account and the message is sent. However, I cant save it to the database. In my views, I type in a message then I send it through the sender. However when checking the `_context.Messages.Add(message);` I get a message:

> "The function requires all threads to run"

so I click the little icon next to it and then it displays null instead of the message above.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
  public DbSet<Message> Messages { get; set; }
  public ApplicationDbContext()
          : base()
{
 }
            
public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
{
                        return new ApplicationDbContext();
}
}

public class MessageController : Controller
    {
private ApplicationDbContext _context;
            
private IMessageSender _messageSender;
public MessageController(IMessageSender messageSender)
{
  this._messageSender = messageSender;
   _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
 }
            
[ActionName("MessageStatus")]
 public ActionResult Send(Message message)
 {
  var viewModel = new MessageViewModel
    {
     Message = new Message()
                           
            
};
 _context.Messages.Add(message);
 _messageSender.Send(message);
  return View("MessageStatus", viewModel);
 }
    }
    
my view
    
@model MessagingWebApplication.ViewModel.MessageViewModel
        
@{ ViewBag.Title = "New";
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
 <h2>New Sms</h2>
        
@using (Html.BeginForm("MessageStatus", "Message"))
 {
 @Html.ValidationSummary()
  <div class="form-group">
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Message.Reciever)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Message.Reciever, new { @class = "form-control" })
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Message.Reciever)
    </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Message.Sender)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Message.Sender, new { @class = "form-control" })
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Message.Sender)
  </div>
   <div class="form-group">
   @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Message.Body)
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Message.Body, new { @class = "form-control" })
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Message.Body)
  </div>
        
  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Message.Id)
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save after adding message

```
 _context.Messages.Add(message);
 _context.SaveChanges();
```

or asynchronously

```
  await _context.Messages.AddAsync(message);
  await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```